# How to Shift all cells down when new text is entered

Tags: excel

I want to create a spreadsheet, where the newest cells are always shown on the top of the page. I've left a blank cell on top of the table for inputting new text. What I want to do is when someone inputs a new text (see picture "New text") everything shifts down by one row. I've looked for solutions online but can't seem to find one. I've attached images to visualize what I want to accomplish. I really hope this makes sense :)

Table before inputting new text:
[image: table before inputing new t]

Table as someone inputs text:
[image]

Table when text is entered:(notice everything shifts down)
[image]

Comment: This requires a solution using VBA. Are you familiar with that?

Comment: @Luuklag Not really, but if you could point me to the right direction I'd be extremely grateful!

Comment: @QuestionEverything Your question is asking about shifting *all* cells down, but your pictures are showing a table.  Is it definitely **all** cells? (ie., "Insert Row")

Comment: @ashleedawg yes, what I meant is that everything shifts down by a row.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table with a heading, where the top-left corner is in cell`A1` then this procedure will insert a new row before `Row #2` after a new value is entered in cell `A2`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'if cell A2 was changed then insert a row at row #2
    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then Rows("2").Insert
End Sub
```

This would need to go in the **Worksheet Module**, which you can get to by **right-clicking** the worksheet's **tab** (at the bottom of the screen), and clicking `View Code`.